# Voltage regulator lm78xx for 220v?

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, dc-dc-converter

I can see that the input voltage of the lm78xx series is 30-40v dc .
We are looking for a voltage regulators system , that will get the 220v ac , and turn it into a : 3.3v, 12v, 24v, dc .

I was thinking if we could  manipulate the `lm` to do that .

I know we can build things, but we are looking for a simple,not expensive solution , to get from the 220v ac ,to these voltages .(should go to a mass production)

We can although put some diodes to convert `ac to dc` , but than again , we couldn't find such a convenient part, like the `lm78xx` , to do that .

It also has to be small in size ( so using transformeter is expensive when its tiny ).

Is there such a thing anyway? a regulator from 220v to 3-24v ??

Comment: If you have to ask how to do this, and you're asking in the way you're asking, then the answer is: No, and hire someone who knows what they're talking about, since you obviously don't seem to have much of a clue. You're thinking of messing with dangerous things you don't understand in ways you don't understand, and that will lead to people dying.

Comment: You didn't even mention how much current you need, seem to be totally unaware of heat dissipation in a linear regulator, don't even seem to be aware of isolation, but yet expect to mass produce this thing.  You are way over your head.  Get someone that knows what they are doing.

Comment: @Majenko: Stupidity does not make it off topic.  The safety issues are actually a valid point of discussion.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Maybe in a proper thread about the safety, yes, but as the question stands, it's asking for something that is far from safe and any answer other than "Don't Do It!" would be a bad answer.  So it should be closed.

Comment: @Majenko: We are not the safety police. If there is a safety problem, point it out, but that is no ground for closing a questions.  Being holier-than-you safety-nannies doesn't serve the site well.

Comment: Try a transformer.

Comment: strange discussion , i actually saw today a voltage regulator in the size of 2x2 cm, that is taking 220v to 12v , for lighting, and it also does not have weight at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stop and actually *think* about this.  If you rectify 220 VAC you get over 310 V DC.  Even if you could find a linear regulator that can drop that to 3.3 V, it would get quite hot even with small output currents.  For example, just 10 mA output would cause over **3 Watts** of heating in the regulator.  Keeping the parts cool and getting rid of the heat will dwarf any advantage you might have gained from a linear regulator.

Then there is also the issue of isolation.  You may not need that if this device only connects to the AC line and has no other external electrical connections.  For example, a simple light doesn't need to be isolated since all the voltages stay internal, but a USB charger absolutely needs to be isolated since it has external connections.

You want some sort of switcher, one way or the other.

Since you say this will be a commercial product, you really need to get someone that knows what they are doing.

Comment: bottom line, i dont really care what can't i do , but what can i do. and i want to give a user a great experience, where he can plug in any voltage that he wants(and the mcu will get 3.3v ) , and that it will be very small . so what you say, there is no small solution to convert 220 to 12v , in 2014 ??

Comment: @Curn: If you don't care to understand the electronics, then we can't help you. You also have to cooperate and answer questions when asked. For one thing, you *still* haven't told us how much current you need at the various DC voltages you want, and enough about this device to know whether those voltages need to be isolated or not. Again, some sort of small switcher is likely the best answer. That will be smaller and cheaper than a linear regulator due to heat management problems alone. A switcher can also be made to isolate, whereas that's impossible for a linear regulator.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, such parts exist, for example the [VB408](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/70064.pdf).

However, I agree 100% with Olin that you probably don't want to do this at all, for both safety reasons and because the efficiency will be incredibly miserable. Buy a switcher or get someone to design one for you.

As Olin's comment below points out, more than a few mA means power dissipation issues with a 240V mains, as a consequence of the miserable efficiency inherent in any linear regulator with a high voltage differential from input to output.

Comment: That's a new one, thanks. I didn't know those existed. It might be good to point out how little current these things can give you when dropping 311 V to 3.3 V. Without a heaksink at at 20degC ambient, they can dissipate only 2 W, which means 7 mA. That's right at the edge with no margin, so rather less in practise. Possibly useful devices for bootstrap supplies though.

Comment: Yes, I think that's the main intended application.

Comment: ...and note that even with a heat sink, the maximum current these can supply (under any circumstances) is 40 mA, so unless  that's sufficient for the purposes at hand, these just won't work (except, I suppose, in some situation where it makes sense to use multiple regulators in parallel).

Comment: That is a nice part.  I'm using a linear ~100V supply to run a piezo.  At some point I'm expecting the linear supply to go away and I'll need a different solution.  Oops, never mind... no stock at DK... and ~$60 http://octopart.com/vb408-stmicroelectronics-8987769

Comment: @GeorgeHerold TI has a 125V part that might do you- TL something-or-other... okay TL783. Tens of thousands in stock.

Comment: Thanks Sphero, I figure I'll wait till the linear supply goes away, and then see what's availible.  But I'm always keeping an eye open for HV supplies... I could do a differential drive so +/- ~50V would be enough.

Comment: No problem. BTW, [this](http://www.chapters.indigo.ca/electronics/sphero-2-0/851897003076-item.html?s_campaign=goo-PLATest&gclid=CNPC_-PijsICFc1_MgodBVMAog&langtype=4105#) is a Sphero. I'm somewhat less spherical on a good day.